# Image doesn't display on browser after uploading with AFNetworking

Tags: objective-c, amazon-s3, afnetworking, afnetworking-3

I have a really strange issue with AFNetworking Image upload. The file uploads properly, and I can see that it has uploaded on my server. When I download the file and open it on mac, the image displays fine.

However, that same image doesn't display on browser. It is somehow that the file is corrupted to not run on only browsers.

Here's the [link](https://ashore-testing.s3.amazonaws.com/uploaded/deliverable96/version1/Artboard.png?1503644151275) to the image. If you try to open in any browser, it will display blank screen.

Any ideas why this is happening? I've spent hours today to figure it out but no avail. I've tried uploading PDF and it worked fine.

Here's my code:

```
NSDictionary *params = @{@"deliverable_ID"     : deliverableID,
                         @"name"    : @"Artboard.png",
                         @"type" : @"png",
                         @"description" : @"Some random png file"};

NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Artboard" ofType:@"png"];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer] multipartFormRequestWithMethod:@"POST" URLString:url parameters:params constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {

    [formData appendPartWithFileURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] name:@"file" fileName:@"Artboard.png" mimeType:@"image/png" error:nil];


} error:nil];
[request setValue:apiToken forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];

AFURLSessionManager *manager = [[AFURLSessionManager alloc] initWithSessionConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration]];

NSURLSessionUploadTask *uploadTask = [manager
                                      uploadTaskWithStreamedRequest:request
                                      progress:nil
                                      completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse * _Nonnull response, id  _Nullable responseObject, NSError * _Nullable error) {
                                          if (error) {

                                              NSString * result = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Error: %@", error];
                                              [delegate printResult:result];
                                          } else {
                                              NSString * result = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",  responseObject];
                                              [delegate printResult:result];
                                          }
                                      }];

[uploadTask resume];
```

Answer (score 0):

The response header for your link contain `Content-Type: application/octet-stream` - this should be `Content-Type: image/png` instead.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the response. I don't think that is the issue though... because this image: https://ashore-testing.s3.amazonaws.com/uploaded/deliverable97/version1/Artboard.png also has octet-stream content type, but shows up the in browser. It is strange however, when I try curl -I the original unbroken image content length is 7838 whereas the broken one is 4629.

Comment: It seems that there is something wrong with my AFNetworking code in Obj-C. I tried uploading using PHP (with multipart/formdata) but the image doesn't get broken like that